# Need help mass finding/replacing portions of a text file

Tags: php, text, replace, find, edit

I have a rather unique situation where I need to make mass edits to an XML (or plain text) file.  Within the XML file, there are several image references such as this one:

```
<image>
  <id>image1</id>
  <dateTaken>Sun Sep 9 10:57:31 GMT-0700 2012</dateTaken>
  <dateAdded>Mon Jun 24 17:44:50 GMT-0700 2013</dateAdded>
  <filename>0881DAF2-80EC-7A25-9CF3-BFD67F4EF764.jpg</filename>
</image>
```

What I need to do is take the file name between `<filename>` and `</filename>`, and use that to replace the portion between `<id>` and `</id>`.  For example in the case above, I would need to replace "image1" with 0881DAF2-80EC-7A25-9CF3-BFD67F4EF764.jpg so it would look like this:

```
<image>
  <id>0881DAF2-80EC-7A25-9CF3-BFD67F4EF764.jpg</id>
  <dateTaken>Sun Sep 9 10:57:31 GMT-0700 2012</dateTaken>
  <dateAdded>Mon Jun 24 17:44:50 GMT-0700 2013</dateAdded>
  <filename>0881DAF2-80EC-7A25-9CF3-BFD67F4EF764.jpg</filename>
</image>
```

There are several hundred of these image references I need to change in this same document.  Using PHP or another method, is there a quick way I can mass edit the document and replace the every ID between `<id>` and `</id>` with the content between `<filename>` and `</filename>`, in every `<image>` `</image>` reference within the document?  Thanks a bunch for any possible help!

Comment: Use one of the many XML parsing libraries available for PHP.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? We're not a code-writing service, we're here to help you fix the problems in your code. But you have to show what you've tried so far, and ask specific questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a root to this xml, you could do something like the following by loading the xml as $xml_string:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);
foreach($xml->children() as $child){
$child->id = $child->filename;
}
$xml->asXml('updated.xml');
```